# How do I remove the Bang Bang?

Tags: javascript, filter, refactoring

I have this filter function:

```
.filter( transaction => !!endDate
      ? (transaction.category === category &&  
         (transaction.time >= startDate &&  transaction.time < endDate))
 : (transaction.category === category && transaction.time >= startDate))
```

But I am not too confident about using the bang bang (!!endDate). How can this be refactored?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like the `!!`, then simply remove it.

All that it does is coerce the "argument" - here `endDate` - to a boolean value. This will happen anyway if you simply use `endDate`, because you're using it as the condition in a ternary expression, which doesn't make sense unless it's boolean anyway. Which means Javascript will coerce it to a Boolean naturally (just like it does with the condition of an `if` statement).

Aside, but: I don't personally think this is the most important point if you want to refactor this though. I'm not totally sure how you should go about it, but this logic is quite hard to read, even though each individual part is simple. I'd certainly be tempted to extract some of the logic into constants which have a more descriptive name.